# radical and socle of the path algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, quivers

Let $Q$ be an infinite quiver without oriented cycle.

Is it true that the radical of $KQ$ is generated by all the arrows?

What can we say about its socle?

Thank you!

Comment: The simple representations of $KQ$ are in one to one correspondence with the vertices of $Q$. All the arrows act trivially on all the simple representations, and they are therefore in the radical. On the other hand, $KQ/<arrows>$ has trivial radical. So the first claim is correct. The socle will be the sum of all simple modules. One can show that the simple module which corresponds to a vertex $v$ will appear in $KQ$ if and only if there is no arrow going into $v$. So the socle is the direct sum of $Ke_v$ such that there is no arrow going into $v$.

Comment: Note this [duplicate question on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2476162/167197).